# assign ssl cerficate from let's encrypt tp BIG-IP F5 Loav balcer (LTM)

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, lets-encrypt, let, f5

I have one webserver there is an SSL certificate from let's encrypt, so I'm trying to create multi-web servers and apply F5 LTM on it, I try to configure the SSL certificate on in f5 but it has not worked, can you help me with instruction or guide for steps how can I apply the SSL certificate

Answer (score 0):

On the BIG-IP LTM, the steps are:

- Create a pool of the web servers
- Upload the LE certificate, chain, and key
- Create a clientssl profile to
  link those assets crypto assets
- Apply the clientssl profile and pool to a virtual server

Details on LTM configuration can be found [here on AskF5](https://techdocs.f5.com/en-us/bigip-14-1-0-1/big-ip-system-ssl-traffic-management-14-1-0-1/about-ssl-offload.html). Note that this is only the LTM component, and that you will need to manage certificate updates every 90 days separately. And when you make updates, you need to either create a new clientssl profile and swap it on the virtual server, or use a transaction to swap the certificate and key as uploading one or the other individually and trying to apply it will result in an error.